# TensorFlow - Importing data from a TensorBoard TFEvent file?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I've run several training sessions with different graphs in TensorFlow. The summaries I set up show interesting results in the training and validation. Now, I'd like to take the data I've saved in the summary logs and perform some statistical analysis and in general plot and look at the summary data in different ways. Is there any existing way to easily access this data?

More specifically, is there any built in way to read a TFEvent record back into Python?

If there is no simple way to do this, [TensorFlow states that all its file formats are protobuf files](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/tool_developers/index.html#protocol-buffers). From my understanding of protobufs (which is limited), I think I'd be able to extract this data if I have the TFEvent protocol specification. Is there an easy way to get ahold of this? Thank you much.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As Fabrizio [says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37306050/3574081), TensorBoard is a great tool for visualizing the contents of your summary logs. However, if you want to perform a custom analysis, you can use [`tf.train.summary_iterator()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37306050/3574081) function to loop over all of the [`tf.Event`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/util/event.proto) and [`tf.Summary`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/summary.proto) protocol buffers in the log:

```
for summary in tf.train.summary_iterator("/path/to/log/file"):
    # Perform custom processing in here.
```

UPDATE for tf2:

```
from tensorflow.python.summary.summary_iterator import summary_iterator
```

You need to import it, that module level is not currently imported by default. On 2.0.0-rc2

Comment: This place has some nice helper functions https://programtalk.com/python-examples/tensorflow.train.summary_iterator/

Comment: We don't have `tf.train.summary_iterator` in TensorFlow 1.8+. Seems change to `tf.python.summary.summary_iterator` now.

Comment: Can't locate summary iterator in tf2

Comment: Time has passed and `summary_iterator` is now to be found under `tf.compat.v1.train`. Also, the Tensorboard package provides the `tensorboard.backend.event_processing` module for those of you who do not want to depend on Tensorflow. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45899735/4375377) for details

Answer (score 41):

To read a TFEvent you can get a Python iterator that yields Event protocol buffers.

```
# This example supposes that the events file contains summaries with a
# summary value tag 'loss'.  These could have been added by calling
# `add_summary()`, passing the output of a scalar summary op created with
# with: `tf.scalar_summary(['loss'], loss_tensor)`.
for e in tf.train.summary_iterator(path_to_events_file):
    for v in e.summary.value:
        if v.tag == 'loss' or v.tag == 'accuracy':
            print(v.simple_value)
```

more info: [summary_iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/train.html#summary_iterator)

Comment: beware of the `simple_value`. At least in my case, it always reported `0.0`. The actual value could be extracted using https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/2745#issuecomment-540274961

Answer (score 32):

You can simply use:

```
tensorboard --inspect --event_file=myevents.out
```

or if you want to filter a specific subset of events of the graph:

```
tensorboard --inspect --event_file=myevents.out --tag=loss
```

If you want to create something more custom you can dig into the

```
/tensorflow/python/summary/event_file_inspector.py
```

to understand how to parse the event files.

Comment: Which version of TensorFlow does this work with? I'm using `0.8`. For me, `--logdir` is always required and despite passing in these other parameters, it seems that TensorBoard just runs as usual ignoring those parameters. Additionally, the `--help` doesn't show either of these parameters. Also, just to make sure I'm not missing something, is this suppose to print something to the terminal screen? Or change what is shown on the TensorBoard page? Or something else? Thanks!

Comment: Following this lead a bit further, I found the `EventAccumulator` class. Which upon loading the file can give all the details of the summary values. I'll update your answer with more detail.

Comment: indeed these parameters are available in tensorflow tip.

Answer (score 14):

Following works as of tensorflow version `2.0.0-beta1`:

```
import os

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import tensor_util

summary_dir = 'tmp/summaries'
summary_writer = tf.summary.create_file_writer('tmp/summaries')

with summary_writer.as_default():
  tf.summary.scalar('loss', 0.1, step=42)
  tf.summary.scalar('loss', 0.2, step=43)
  tf.summary.scalar('loss', 0.3, step=44)
  tf.summary.scalar('loss', 0.4, step=45)


from tensorflow.core.util import event_pb2
from tensorflow.python.lib.io import tf_record

def my_summary_iterator(path):
    for r in tf_record.tf_record_iterator(path):
        yield event_pb2.Event.FromString(r)

for filename in os.listdir(summary_dir):
    path = os.path.join(summary_dir, filename)
    for event in my_summary_iterator(path):
        for value in event.summary.value:
            t = tensor_util.MakeNdarray(value.tensor)
            print(value.tag, event.step, t, type(t))
```

the code for `my_summary_iterator` is copied from `tensorflow.python.summary.summary_iterator.py` - there was no way to import it at runtime.

Comment: I'm analysing tfevent files generated by the tensorflow object detection api so, just using `value.simple_value` always yielded `0`, even though in the tensorboard gui, there were clearly different numbers. the line `t = tensor_util.MakeNdarray(value.tensor)` seems to do the trick for me

Comment: Thank you for this! It seem like in tensorflow 2.4 at least the `tensor_util.MakeNdarray(value.tensor)` is required to access the value if it is a custom metric as opposed to the defaults from keras. If you write it using `tf.summary.scalar()` it gets saved as a tensor for some reason instead of a scalar, and `value.simple_value` always returns `0`.

Answer (score 10):

Here is a complete example for obtaining values from a scalar.  You can see the message specification for the Event protobuf message [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/framework/summary.proto)

```
import tensorflow as tf


for event in tf.train.summary_iterator('runs/easy_name/events.out.tfevents.1521590363.DESKTOP-43A62TM'):
    for value in event.summary.value:
        print(value.tag)
        if value.HasField('simple_value'):
            print(value.simple_value)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the script [serialize_tensorboard](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/tensorboard/scripts/serialize_tensorboard.py), which will take in a logdir and write out all the data in json format.

You can also use an [EventAccumulator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/backend/event_processing/event_accumulator.py) for a convenient Python API (this is the same API that TensorBoard uses).

Comment: As of Tensorboard version 1.1, the serialize_tensorboard script is no longer available.

Answer (score 5):

There are 2 native ways to read the event files mentioned in [this post](https://tbparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/raw.html):

1. Event Accumulator

   ```py
   >>> from tensorboard.backend.event_processing.event_accumulator import EventAccumulator
   >>> event_acc = EventAccumulator(event_file)
   >>> event_acc.Reload() 
   <tensorboard.backend.event_processing.event_accumulator.EventAccumulator object at ...>
   >>> print(event_acc.Tags())
   {'images': [], 'audio': [], 'histograms': [], 'scalars': ['y=2x'], 'distributions': [], 'tensors': [], 'graph': False, 'meta_graph': False, 'run_metadata': []}
   >>> for e in event_acc.Scalars('y=2x'):
   ...   print(e.step, e.value)
   0 0.0
   1 2.0
   2 4.0
   3 6.0
   4 8.0
   ```
2. Summary Iterator

   ```py
   >>> import tensorflow as tf
   >>> from tensorflow.python.summary.summary_iterator import summary_iterator
   >>> for e in summary_iterator(event_file):
   ...   for v in e.summary.value:
   ...     if v.tag == 'y=2x':
   ...       print(e.step, v.simple_value)
   0 0.0
   1 2.0
   2 4.0
   3 6.0
   4 8.0
   ```

For multiple event files or other event types (e.g., histograms), you can use [tbparse](https://github.com/j3soon/tbparse) to parse the event logs into a pandas DataFrame and process it locally. You can open an [issue](https://github.com/j3soon/tbparse/issues) if you encountered any question during parsing. (I'm the author of [tbparse](https://github.com/j3soon/tbparse))

Note: TensorBoard can parse the event logs into DataFrames only if you uploaded your event logs to [TensorBoard.dev](https://tensorboard.dev/) ([source](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/dataframe_api)), and is currently not possible to use it offline/locally.

Answer (score 1):

Late 2020 versions of TensorFlow and TensorFlow Datasets recommends a different approach. Use [`tf.data.TFRecordDataset`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/TFRecordDataset) and [`event_pb2`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Example):

```
from os import path, listdir
from operator import contains
from functools import partial
from itertools import chain
from json import loads

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.core.util import event_pb2

# From https://github.com/Suor/funcy/blob/0ee7ae8/funcy/funcs.py#L34-L36
def rpartial(func, *args):
    """Partially applies last arguments."""
    return lambda *a: func(*(a + args))


tensorboard_logdir = "/tmp"


# Or you could just glob… for *tfevents*:
list_dir = lambda p: map(partial(path.join, p), listdir(p))

for event in filter(rpartial(contains, "tfevents"),
                    chain.from_iterable(
                        map(list_dir,
                            chain.from_iterable(
                                map(list_dir,
                                    filter(rpartial(contains, "_epochs_"),
                                           list_dir(tensorboard_logdir))))))):
    print(event)
    for raw_record in tf.data.TFRecordDataset(event):
        for value in event_pb2.Event.FromString(raw_record.numpy()).summary.value:
            print("value: {!r} ;".format(value))
            if value.tensor.ByteSize():
                t = tf.make_ndarray(value.tensor)
                if hasattr(event, "step"):
                    print(value.tag, event.step, t, type(t))
                elif type(t).__module__ == np.__name__:
                    print("t: {!r} ;".format(np.vectorize(loads)(t)))
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this. It assumes that you only want to see tags you've logged more than once whose values are floats and returns the results as a `pd.DataFrame`. Just call `metrics_df = parse_events_file(path)`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

def is_interesting_tag(tag):
    if 'val' in tag or 'train' in tag:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def parse_events_file(path: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    metrics = defaultdict(list)
    for e in tf.train.summary_iterator(path):
        for v in e.summary.value:

            if isinstance(v.simple_value, float) and is_interesting_tag(v.tag):
                metrics[v.tag].append(v.simple_value)
            if v.tag == 'loss' or v.tag == 'accuracy':
                print(v.simple_value)
    metrics_df = pd.DataFrame({k: v for k,v in metrics.items() if len(v) > 1})
    return metrics_df
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This works for me for latest TF version

Make sure to replace this path with your path

```
import tensorflow as tf

for e in tf.compat.v1.train.summary_iterator("logs/runs/events.out.tfevents.1698427949.9861bc6d10b6.26.0"):
    for v in e.summary.value:
        print(v.tag)
        print(v.simple_value)
    print('-' * 10)
```