# Tensorflow - Tensorboard Event Accumulator get Tensor from TensorEvent

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, tensorboard

I am working with Tensorflow and Tensorboard version 1.14.
I would like to perform some off-line analysis starting from Data I have saved during training using the [tf.summary.tensor_summary()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.14/api_docs/python/tf/summary/tensor_summary)

I am not able to recover the data saved with the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304461/tensorflow-importing-data-from-a-tensorboard-tfevent-file), using the tf.train.summary_iterator which does recover scalar data but not the data I saved with the tensor_summary method.

Though with the [EventAccumulator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/blob/master/tensorboard/backend/event_processing/event_accumulator.py) object I am able to recover the data I have saved, that it is returned as a TensorEvent Object which has the following attributes:

1. step
2. wall_time
3. tensor_proto
4. tensor_content

Thing is that I would like to convert this data into numpy array, the TensorEvent object sure has all the information needed (tensor_proto for type and shape, tensor_content for values), but not being a Tensor does not have a .value or a .numpy() method. **So I do I trasform a TensorEvent Object into a numpy array?** or equivalently into a Tensor object then into a numpy array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`tf.make_ndarray`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_ndarray) to convert a [`TensorProto`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r2.1/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.proto) into a NumPy array:

```
tensor_np = tf.make_ndarray(tensor_event.tensor_proto)
```