# Store TensorFlow/TensorBoard data in Elastic or Prometheus

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Is there a way to feed live training (summary) metrics from TensorFlow/TensorBoard into Elastic or Prometheus, so I can visualize these outside of TensorBoard? I'd like to combine my visualizations with other metrics that are not available to TensorBoard.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the tfevents files as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/40029298/179444 and forward them to a prometheus pushgateway, expose them for scraping or index them in elasticsearch.